# Jira Python custom field values and attributes

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I have a question.
I work with Jira via Python and there was a need to get the value of the Insight object, which is located in the custom field. For example: Custom Field: Human, customfield_10123.

Objects available for selection in this field:

Alex (name)
А123 (id)
**(some attributes)**
blonde (hair_color)
1,25 (height)
30 (weight)

I have this code:

```
issue = jira.issue(issueID)
print(issue.fields.customfield_10123[0])
```

Result: Alex (A123)

But I want to get some attributes.

```
issue = jira.issue(issueID)
print(issue.fields.customfield_10123[0].hair_color)
```

Result what I want: blonde

Perhaps you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: try `print(issue.fields.customfield_10123[0].hair_color[0])` ?

Comment: I had AttributeError(